# WebException Unable to connect to the remote server System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

**InnerExeption:**

> WebException Unable to connect to the remote server System.Net.Sockets.Socket GetConnection(System.Net.PooledStream, System.Object, Boolean, System.Net.IPAddress ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef)
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
>     at ContactWebApp.Utility.SendEmail.EmailSend(String SenderEmail, String Subject, String Message, Boolean IsBodyHtml) in

I get this kind of error message when I sending email.
Its work successfully when I send email from local ....
But if I try from server then....

Anyone have any idea about it?.

Comment: Yeah, you couldn't connect to the remote server. This doesn't seem like a programming issue at all.

Comment: But @John its work from local, but not from sever do you have any idea?

Comment: Firewall issues on the server? IP whitelist on the SMTP server?

Comment: may be its an issue  @John let me check Thank you.